# how do i select previous row's value and past in current row?

Tags: mysql

Im using mysql and This is the entry I have in my current table.

So here ***previous balance*** for current month should be the ***remaining balance*** of previous month. How do I get this value from previous row of database.

```
Previous_balance Remaining_Balance
        0.00        42.64
        0.00        627.69
        0.00        45.54
        0.00        67.60
```

The result should be

```
Previous_balance Remaining_Balance
        0.00        42.64
        42.64       627.69
        627.69      45.54
        45.54       67.60
```

I have ID as PK and I want store the new previous_balance in database and print on form. So I can calculate Monthly charges and usage and other stuff. Thanks for answers.

Comment: does mySQL support LEAD and LAG functions?

Comment: Do you have any other row idenfiers (a unique ID, date or month/year fields)?  If so, please update your question so that we can help.

Comment: I have ID as PK. Actually I want store the last month remain balance as new previous_balance for current month in database and print on PHP form. So I can calculate Monthly charges and usage and other stuff on it. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that the `id` field is ordered, try this:

```
UPDATE Balances 
  SET b1.Previous_balance = COALESCE((SELECT b2.Remaining_Balance 
                                      FROM Balances b2 
                                      WHERE b2.id < b1.id 
                                      ORDER BY b2.id DESC 
                                      LIMIT 1),0) 
FROM Balances b1
```

I don't have an installation of mySQL, so I can't vouch for all the syntax.  I know the SELECT statement works though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`SELECT LAST(remaingBalance) as previousBalance, FIRST(remaingBalance) as remaingBalance
FROM ...

WHERE ...

GROUP BY month`

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

Comment: Actually I want store the last month remain balance as new previous_balance for current month in database and print on PHP form. So I can calculate Monthly charges and usage and other stuff on it. Thanks for answers